# How to combine multiple queries?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have millions of documents to index. Each document has fields `doc_id`, `doc_title` and several fields `doc_content`.

```
import requests

index = 'test'

JSON = {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "doc_id":      {"type": "keyword"},
            "doc_title":   {"type": "text"   },
            "doc_content": {"type": "text"   }
        }
    }
}

r = requests.put(f'http://127.0.0.1:9200/{index}', json=JSON)
```

To minimize the size of the index, I keep `doc_title` and `doc_content` separate.

```
docs = [
    {"doc_id": 1, "doc_title": "good"},
    {"doc_id": 1, "doc_content": "a"},
    {"doc_id": 1, "doc_content": "b"},

    {"doc_id": 2, "doc_title": "good"},
    {"doc_id": 2, "doc_content": "c"},
    {"doc_id": 2, "doc_content": "d"},

    {"doc_id": 3, "doc_title": "bad"},
    {"doc_id": 3, "doc_content": "a"},
    {"doc_id": 3, "doc_content": "e"}
]

for doc in docs:
    r = requests.post(f'http://127.0.0.1:9200/{index}/_doc', json=doc)
```

**query_1:**

```
JSON = {
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "doc_title": "good"
        }
    }
}

r = requests.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:9200/{index}/_search', json=JSON)

[x['_source'] for x in r.json()['hits']['hits']]
```

> [{'doc_id': 1, 'doc_title': 'good'}, {'doc_id': 2, 'doc_title': 'good'}]

**query_2:**

```
JSON = {
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "doc_content": "a"
        }
    }
}

r = requests.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:9200/{index}/_search', json=JSON)

[x['_source'] for x in r.json()['hits']['hits']]
```

> [{'doc_id': 1, 'doc_content': 'a'}, {'doc_id': 3, 'doc_content': 'a'}]

**How to combine query_1 and query_2?**

I need something like this:

```
JSON = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"doc_title": "good"}},
                {"match": {"doc_content": "a"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}

r = requests.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:9200/{index}/_search', json=JSON)

[x['_source'] for x in r.json()['hits']['hits']]
```

> []

Desired result:

> [{'doc_id': 1, 'doc_title': 'good', 'doc_content': 'a'}]

Comment: sorry can't understand you, previously you said that in your model  could not exist doc_title and doc_content in the same document to minimize the size of the index (is the opposite, in this way you create two docs for each entity), then you said that you expect as desired result a document with both fields (that you haven't created)??????

Comment: @Lupanoide In my example, I have only 2 `doc_content` fields per document. But in real data, each document can have hundreds of `doc_content` fields. I save `doc_title`.

Comment: @Lupanoide `Are the documents with doc_content and doc_title in different indices?` No, they are in the same index. `if in your index doesn't exist document with both fields, why the desired result has both fields` I think this is possible with [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html). But I can not find a suitable function for this.

Comment: this answer is one of the worst way to solve your problem. A nested query needs a lot more ram than a normal query. nested fields are thought with few data then you should deserialize your data. But in your scenario, you could be solved keeping the data on the same level, e.g. {"doc_data":"abc","doc_content":"abc","doc_title":"abc"} and keep all simpler. Now you will need much more resources to run your solution and the queries will be much slower. Good luck with your cluster!

Comment: @Lupanoide I agree with you that keeping data at the same level is the best solution. But `doc_title` is long and `doc_content` is short. I can have hundreds `doc_content` per document. I currently have 400 GB of data in a cluster. With the same level I will receive 5-6x increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice to separate `doc_title` & `doc_content` -- you're not really miniming anything.

Go with this:

```
docs = [
    {"doc_id": 1, "doc_title": "good", "doc_content": ["a", "b"]},
    {"doc_id": 2, "doc_title": "good", "doc_content": ["c", "d"]},
    {"doc_id": 3, "doc_title": "bad", "doc_content": ["a", "e"]}
]

for doc in docs:
    r = requests.post(f'http://127.0.0.1:9200/{index}/_doc', json=doc)
```

and your query will work just as expected. `a` and `b` are supposed to be shared by `doc_id=1` anyways, aren't they?

---

UPDATE -- make the `contents` syntactically [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "contents": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "doc_content": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "doc_id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "doc_title": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }

  }
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "doc_id": 1,
  "doc_title": "good",
  "contents": [
    {"doc_content": "a"},
    {"doc_content": "b"}
  ]
}

GET test/_search
{
  "_source": ["doc_title", "inner_hits"], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "doc_title": "good"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "contents",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "contents.doc_content": "a"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
[
  {
    "_index":"test",
    "_type":"_doc",
    "_id":"sySOoXEBdiyDG0RsIq21",
    "_score":0.98082924,
    "_source":{
      "doc_title":"good"               <------
    },
    "inner_hits":{
      "contents":{
        "hits":{
          "total":1,
          "max_score":0.6931472,
          "hits":[
            {
              "_index":"test",
              "_type":"_doc",
              "_id":"sySOoXEBdiyDG0RsIq21",
              "_nested":{
                "field":"contents",
                "offset":0
              },
              "_score":0.6931472,
              "_source":{
                "doc_content":"a"          <-----
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my example, I have only 2 `doc_content` fields per document. But in real data, each document can have hundreds of `doc_content` fields. I save `doc_title`.

Comment: How to do query to get only `a`? `[{'doc_id': 1, 'doc_title': 'good', 'doc_content': ['a', 'b']}]`

Comment: Looks like a use case for a nested mapping. I'll update my answer.

Comment: What does this mean: `The mapping definition cannot be nested under a type [_doc] unless include_type_name is set to true.`?

Comment: Remove the `"_doc": {` outer braces in the mapping. I'm using an older version of ES.